# Text rendering issues in Gnome Desktop Manager 3

Tags: debian-jessie, gdm

I did an apt-get update on a debian 8 box and it really messed up my system.

First of all, it changed my window manager to gdm3.

The problem I have is that the fonts are some how messed up. When I click on 'Activities' I get the panel of icon on the left of the screen which is for applications.

The icons show up correctly, and the application launches when I left click on it. However, when I right click on the icon, a popup/tooltip shows up. Normally this popup/tooltip should show some text like "remove from panel" or something like that.

However, no text shows up. It is like the text is being rendered the same color as the background so I can not see it.

Also, all other gnome 3 right click popup/tooltips likewise show no text. If I right click on the very upper-right on the panel, I get the logout popup. It shows the audio volume slider. But for the user (me) it shows random text -- not my login name.

Anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks

Comment: gdm isn't a window manager nor a desktop manager – it's a display manager, whose task is to start Xorg and the WM. Your window manager is gnome-shell.